# SSAS model "Name" and "Id" fields get overwritten after saving a change in the designer

Tags: powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular

We have an SSAS model that we are developing in Visual Studio that feeds a Power BI report.
The .bim file has 2 fields "Name" and "Id" that should be equal to a certain value (in our case is "Reporting_AS_Model"). However, each time I go in the designer mode of SSAS and change anything (could be as simple as adding a comma to a measure) and then save the change those two fields get overwritten with value "SemanticModel" and we need to go in the code and manually change them.

How can I avoid this issue?

Fields "Name" and "Id" get changed from "Reporting_AS_Model" to "SemanticModel" value when a change to the model is saved. It should not change those 2 fields with no reason.